# Is there a hack to change the color of text underline in iOS Safari

Tags: css, mobile-safari

It seems that text-decoration-color is not compatible with mobile Safari.

Is there a workaround to change the color of the text underline?

I have tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
.underline {
    border-bottom: 2px !important;
    border-bottom-color: yellow !important;
    text-decoration: none !important; 
}
```

Comment: `border-bottom: 2px solid yellow;` or change `border-bottom: 2px;` to `border-bottom-width: 2px;`

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Please add it as an answer so I can give you a checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `border-bottom` property for link.

`border-bottom: 2px solid yellow;` or change `border-bottom: 2px;` to `border-bottom-width: 2px;`

Demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e8zd6o27/1/)

Comment: the following didn't work: ```.underline {
border-bottom: 2px !important;
border-bottom-color: yellow !important;
text-decoration: none !important;
}```